# How do I find out which version and version number of MS 365 Word I'm running?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-365

I'm using a program titled Word at https://www.microsoft365.com/

Help has no About box. [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/servicesagreement/#serviceslist) lists six versions. [Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-tab-marks-in-word-84a53213-5d02-404a-b022-09cae1a3958b#ID0EBBD=Windows) refers to two versions, but the nearest match to here ("Windows") refers to a command

[image]

that's missing from my version:

[image]

[image]

Note: Re "This question is off-topic.", no it's not. It meets the site requirement "Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application".

Comment: Your question is very difficult to follow.  If this image is from your app, then I circled the likely location for the info  [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3XoT.png "click for image").  You will see a `Build:` number on that screen

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Goodness knows why About has been moved from Help to File.